# How can I determine that text is part of a string literal when writing a syntax highlighter

Tags: objective-c, syntax-highlighting, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I am currently writing a library what will take a NSString and output an NSAttributedString that has been formatted for the specified language. I am planning on iterating through parts of the string using NSRange, but I have run into a few roadblocks. First, how can I make sure that I am not formatting code that is actually string literal. If you have any suggestions or other projects that I should look at, please let me know!

```
- (NSAttributedString *)formatString:(NSString *)string forLanguage:(STXLanguage)language {
    NSMutableArray *wordsInCode = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableAttributedString *formattedString = [NSMutableAttributedString new];
    NSInteger *locationOfCurrentRange = 0;
    for (NSInteger a = 0; a < string.length; a ++) {
        NSRange currentRange = NSMakeRange(locationOfCurrentRange, a);
    }
    for (NSInteger a = 0; a < wordsInCode.count; a ++) {
        NSAttributedString *stringInWordsInCode = wordsInCode[a];
        [formattedString appendAttributedString:stringInWordsInCode];
    }
    return formattedString;
}
```

Comment: Traditionally we would use a lexer like "lex" or ad-hoc parsing such as you are doing. You might consider using `NSScanner`.